# what is the maximum size can i write into outputstream in java

Tags: java, rest, csv, download, outputstream

I have a requirement in my web application,i.e, to download data as csv from db, without creating a physical file in the server.So i've decided to write to outputstreame directly.

So what is the maximum bytes of data can i write to OutputStream.

my code is something like below.

```
   StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
                @Override
                public void write(OutputStream os) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
                    try {
                        -----------some code------
                         while(rs.next){
                            os.write(rs.getString(0).getBytes()+","+rs.getString(1).getBytes());
                         }

                        os.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new WebApplicationException(e);
                    }
                }
            };
```

Comment: It depends upon your implementation of OutputStream, your JVM configuration etc.

Comment: @Andy Turner What if i wrote 2^32 -1 chars into outputstream object and still writing...
   os.write(2^32-1 chars);
   os.write(jshjaskjf);
<br/>
how to increase the size?

Comment: It's a *stream*, so it doesn't store the bytes anywhere. You can keep writing beyond 2^32 bytes.

Comment: @laune but i need to send it through REST service over network.

Comment: That's just an architecture class. You need to identify the API you are supposed to use. So it's not "writing bytes to a stream", as your question says.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
```

public class BigFile{
        public static void main(String asd[]){

```
        String fileString = "D:/INSAn/error.log";
        try {
            BigFile bigFile = new BigFile(fileString);
            for (String line : bigFile)
                System.out.println("line : " + line);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
    }
}
Hey you can use the above code , it will read file of any size.I tested it for 1 GB file.
```